# Restore keras seq2seq model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm working with the keras seq2seq example here:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_seq2seq.py

I would like to persist the vocabulary and decoder so that I can load it again later, and apply it to new sequences.

While the code calls model.save(), this is insufficient because I can see the decoding setup referencing a number of other variables which are deep pointers into the trained model:

```
encoder_model = Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states)

decoder_state_input_h = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
decoder_state_input_c = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
decoder_states_inputs = [decoder_state_input_h, decoder_state_input_c]
decoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = decoder_lstm(
    decoder_inputs, initial_state=decoder_states_inputs)
decoder_states = [state_h, state_c]
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)
decoder_model = Model(
    [decoder_inputs] + decoder_states_inputs,
    [decoder_outputs] + decoder_states)
```

I would like to translate this code to determine encoder_inputs, encoder_states, latent_dim, decoder_inputs from a model loaded from disk. It's ok to assume I know the model architecture in advance.  Is there a straightforward way to do this?

*Update*:
I have made some progress using the decoder construction code and pulling out the layer inputs/outputs as needed.

```
encoder_inputs = model.input[0] #input_1
decoder_inputs = model.input[1] #input_2
encoder_outputs, state_h_enc, state_c_enc = model.layers[2].output # lstm_1
_, state_h_dec, state_c_dec = model.layers[3].output # lstm_2
decoder_outputs = model.layers[4].output # dense_1

encoder_states = [state_h_enc, state_c_enc]
encoder_model = Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states)

latent_dim = 256 # TODO: infer this from the model. Should match lstm_1 outputs.

decoder_state_input_h = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
decoder_state_input_c = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
decoder_states_inputs = [decoder_state_input_h, decoder_state_input_c]

decoder_states = [state_h_dec, state_c_dec]

decoder_model = Model(
    [decoder_inputs] + decoder_states_inputs,
    [decoder_outputs] + decoder_states)
```

However, when I try to construct the decoder model, I encounter this error:

```
RuntimeError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(?, ?, 96), dtype=float32) at layer "input_1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

As a test I tried Model(decoder_inputs,decoder_outputs) with the same result. It's not clear to me what is disconnected from the graph, since these layers are loaded from the model.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, I solved this problem and the decoder is producing reasonable results. In my code above I missed a couple details in the decoder step, specifically that it `call()s` the LSTM and Dense layers in order to wire them up. In addition, the new decoder inputs need unique names so they don't collide with input_1 and input_2 (this detail smells like a keras bug).

```
encoder_inputs = model.input[0] #input_1
encoder_outputs, state_h_enc, state_c_enc = model.layers[2].output # lstm_1
encoder_states = [state_h_enc, state_c_enc]
encoder_model = Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states)

decoder_inputs = model.input[1] #input_2
decoder_state_input_h = Input(shape=(latent_dim,),name='input_3')
decoder_state_input_c = Input(shape=(latent_dim,),name='input_4')
decoder_states_inputs = [decoder_state_input_h, decoder_state_input_c]
decoder_lstm = model.layers[3]
decoder_outputs, state_h_dec, state_c_dec = decoder_lstm(
    decoder_inputs, initial_state=decoder_states_inputs)
decoder_states = [state_h_dec, state_c_dec]
decoder_dense = model.layers[4]
decoder_outputs=decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

decoder_model = Model(
    [decoder_inputs] + decoder_states_inputs,
    [decoder_outputs] + decoder_states)
```

A big drawback with this code is the fact we know the full architecture in advance. I would like to eventually be able to load an architecture-agnostic decoder.

Comment: I created a Keras PR here to provide a working example: [https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/9119](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/9119)

Answer (score 5):

At a point in the code of the Keras seq2seq example you will have a finished encoder and decoder model. You can save the architecture and weights of these models to disk and load them later. The following works for me:

Save the models to disk:

```
with open('encoder_model.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(encoder_model.to_json())
encoder_model.save_weights('encoder_model_weights.h5')

with open('decoder_model.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(decoder_model.to_json())
decoder_model.save_weights('decoder_model_weights.h5')
```

Later load the encoder and decoder:

```
def load_model(model_filename, model_weights_filename):
    with open(model_filename, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
        model = model_from_json(f.read())
    model.load_weights(model_weights_filename)
    return model

encoder = load_model('encoder_model.json', 'encoder_model_weights.h5')
decoder = load_model('decoder_model.json', 'decoder_model_weights.h5')
```

During prediction you will also need a number of other data, like number of encoder/decoder tokens, dictionaries mapping char to index etc. You can just save these to file after training and load them later, just like with the models.